# How do I prevent a DataGridView from autoscrolling when the data is always coming in the first row?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am not much familiar with Win forms.
I am using a dataGridView in my application. Data is always filling the first row of the gridview. I am also using a scroll bar property. All things are working fine except one that whenever user is scrolling down and selecting any row from the gridview; Scrollbar Control is automatically go Upwards and the first row is get selected.
I want to prevent scrollbar to go automatically if user selecting any row after scrolling and after some time(10-15 seconds) it should continue to work as before. I mean as it is working now.

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example so we can reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Do you have, by any mean, any kind of auto-refresh or timer based update that would refill your datagridview?